# How to open a file using its absolute path?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to open a file using its absolute path?

```
await File('c:/Users/rozerro/AndroidStudioProjects/rxdart_streams/assets/sonet.txt')
            .openRead()
            .transform(utf8.decoder)
            .transform(LineSplitter())
            .toList();
```

as well as

```
c:\\Users\\rozerro\\AndroidStudioProjects\\rxdart_streams\\assets\\sonet.txt
```

The error

> E/flutter ( 4943): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)]
> Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path =
> 'c:/Users/rozerro/AndroidStudioProjects/rxdart_streams/assets/sonet.txt'
> (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: Can you paste your path into an Explorer Window and the file opens? How do you know the path is correct? In addition, you tagged this dart. Is it pure dart on Windows, or is it maybe Flutter on a emulated device?

Comment: @nvoigt it's flutter. this path is correct in windows `C:\Users\rozerro\AndroidStudioProjects\rxdart_streams\assets\sonet.txt`

Comment: So... is it Flutter on a Device or Flutter for Windows Desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. You cannot access a file on your local PC from an app deployed on your smartphone.

Since your text file is in a folder named assets, I assume it is some kind of file you want to have deployed with your app. In flutter that is called an "asset" and you can read up on how to achieve that in the [documentation about assets and images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images).

In short, your pubspec.yaml file needs to have an entry for it:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/sonet.txt
```

And then you can access it in your source with this method:

```
final textFromFile = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/sonet.txt');
```

Comment: actually the app is running on an emulator

Comment: Well, if the emulator is any good, it will emulate the fact that the smartphone cannot do that.